# How can I map arbitrary points on a google map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a set of custom locations, and I have a web page.

On my web page, I have a functioning Google Map (using v3 of the API).

If you enter an address, it will center itself on that address.  Nothing exciting.

When the user enters a location, I want the map to include any of my custom locations within a certain radius of the location they entered.

Can someone point me to the API reference for doing this?  I know it cannot be hard, but for the life of me I can't find a good reference or example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be pretty easy using Markers.  The AddCustomLocationsToMap function does the real work, below.  Thanks to [this blog post](http://www.tdmarketing.co.nz/blog/2011/03/09/create-marker-with-custom-labels-in-google-maps-api-v3/) for the starting point.

```
function FocusMapOnAddress(address) {
    var mapCenter;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            cdamap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            mapCenter = results[0].geometry.location;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: cdamap,
                position: mapCenter
            });
        } else {
            alert("Address could not be resolved due to an error: " + status);
        }
    });

    //if we actually know where they are (i.e., valid address) then zoom and show locations
    if (mapCenter != null) {
        AddCustomLocationsToMap();
        SetMapZoomLevel(mapCenter, SearchRadiusInMeters());
    }
}

var locations = [
    ['High Park', 43.6516699, -79.4652915, 4,'Our High Park Office is open from 9am - 5pm'],
    ['King Street CDA Office', 32.775692, -79.932863, 5,'Our King Stret Office is open from 8am - 4pm'],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3,''],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2,''],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1,'']
];

function AddCustomLocationsToMap() {
    //show custom locations, pulled from the "locations" array
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: cdamap
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(HTMLForLocation(i));
                infowindow.open(cdamap, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}

function HTMLForLocation(idx) {
    //return HTML for display to the user when they click on the specified location
    var selectedLocation = locations[idx];
    if (selectedLocation != null) {
        return '<b>' + locations[idx][0] + '</b>' + '<br/>' + locations[idx][4];
    }
    else {
        return "Unknown location";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the distance between two points by

```
computeDistanceBetween
```

[more info here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en-US#spherical)

more about the geometry library [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry?hl=el#SphericalGeometry)